# VBA tool to determine SpreadsheetType from given spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wish to use the `TransferSpreadsheet` command to link or import a spreadsheet to Access 2010.
It requires a value for `SpreadsheetType` (drawn from the `AcSpreadSheetType` enumeration).
What is the Access VBA tool to determine SpreadsheetType from given spreadsheet filename?
Maybe the only means is to examine the file extension and do a lookup?
If you've solved this problem before, please share.

Comment: I've given a simple solution below. If you have something better...

Answer (score 1):

Given that there seems to be a definite one-to-many mapping from file extension to specific Excel formats (see table below), I decided to keep it (very) simple, and assume only a few possible formats are likely.

My code:

```
Private Function excel_type(file As String) As Integer
    Dim ext As String
    ext = LCase(extension(file))
    excel_type = IIf(ext = "xlsx", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                 IIf(ext = "xls", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                 IIf(ext = "xml", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, -1)))
End Function

Public Function extension(file As String) As String
    extension = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, "."))
End Function
```

Reference table (feel free to edit for completeness):

```
Extn    SpreadsheetType          Value  File format

?       acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3      0  Microsoft Excel 3.0
?       acSpreadsheetTypeExcel4      6  Microsoft Excel 4.0
xls     acSpreadsheetTypeExcel5      5  Microsoft Excel 5.0
xls     acSpreadsheetTypeExcel7      5  Microsoft Excel 95
xls     acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8      8  Microsoft Excel 97
xls     acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9      8  Microsoft Excel 2000
xlsx    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12     9  Microsoft Excel 2010
xml     acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml 10  Microsoft Excel 2010 XML
?       acSpreadsheetTypeLotusWJ2    4
?       acSpreadsheetTypeLotusWJ1    
?       acSpreadsheetTypeLotusWJ3    
?       acSpreadsheetTypeLotusWJ4
```