# Get acSpreadSheetType for acLink

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to link an external table to Access with the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` command.

My code is:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, import_type, TableName, internal_filepath, True
```

The problem with this code is, that I get inconsistent errors regarding the file-type (Error 3274). I cant reproduce the error.

The value `import_type` is based on a function getting (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385705/vba-tool-to-determine-spreadsheettype-from-given-spreadsheet)) the version of the excel-file:

```
Function excel_type(File As String) As Integer
    Dim ext As String
    ext = LCase(extension(File))
    excel_type = IIf(ext = "xlsx", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                 IIf(ext = "xls", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                 IIf(ext = "xml", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, -1)))
End Function

Public Function extension(File As String) As String
    extension = Right(File, Len(File) - InStrRev(File, "."))
End Function
```

It returned `"9"` for `.xlsx` which is correct, but I still sporadically get this error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
excel_type = IIf(ext = "xlsx", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
             IIf(ext = "xls", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
             IIf(ext = "xlsb", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, -1)))
```

Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using successive [`iif`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) statements, I might suggest using a single [`select case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) statement, for example:

```vb
Function ExcelType(strFnm As String) As Long
    Select Case LCase(Right(strFnm, Len(strFnm) - InStrRev(strFnm, ".")))
        Case "xlsx", "xml"
            ExcelType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
        Case "xls"
            ExcelType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
        Case Else
            ExcelType = -1
    End Select
End Function
```